Why do spacings in GraphicsGrid not work properly?
I generate two plots with no upper and bottom border like this
plots = {
  {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Small, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {0, 0}}]},
  {Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Small, 
    ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {0, 0}}]}
  }

which outputs

Then I combine them with GraphicsGrid
GraphicsGrid[plots, Spacings -> 0, Frame -> All]

which gives

Spacings is not 0 as expected. Why is that? How to eliminate the spacing between two plots in GraphicsGrid?

Update
As comments say, MMA 14 has bug. MMA 14.1 works for the above example. However, if we define
plots = {{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
    ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {Automatic, 0}}], 
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
    ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {Automatic, 0}}]}}

and run
GraphicsGrid[plots, Spacings -> 0]

we still got spacing which should not exist.


How to eliminate the spacing between two plots in GraphicsGrid I am not sure why, but if you type ImagePadding->0 in the Plot command, then it works, but you lose the axis ticks on the left and right also. Another option which might work for you is to use GraphicsGrid[plots, Spacings -> {0, -12}, Frame -> All] now it remove the spacings between.  Again, I do not know why it did not work the way you did it.  https://i.sstatic.net/Dndk9z4E.png

I got this: https://i.sstatic.net/ggiHbVIz.png -- I guess that's what you would like to have.

@Nasser Yeah, I know ImagePadding->0 works but lose ticks. However, Spacings -> {0, -12} is rather arbitrary. If we can make it automatic, then I can accept it.

@MichaelE2 Hi, Michael E2. Did you get your result with Spacings -> 0? By the way, I am aware of the ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"] designed for this purpose. However, for some unknown reason, it is extremely slow in my version of Mathematica. Not only does it generate plots slowly, but the entire frontend becomes almost unresponsive once the plots appear on the screen. That is why I am seeking some simpler way to realize it.

In MMA version 14.1 it seems to work.

@DanielHuber that is correct. I did not notice I was using V 14 and not V 14.1 when I tried it. It looks like a bug that was fixed. Screen shot https://i.sstatic.net/E656m4ZP.png

@DanielHuber Thank you for the information, it fixes some case. But try plots = {   {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400,      ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {Automatic, 0}}],     Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 5}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400,      ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {Automatic, 0}}]}}, it fails to eliminate the spacing again.

Like DanielHuber, I used your code in V14.1

This is not a direct answer to my post, But I think it is worth writing down.
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"] developed by Lukas Lang is great for this kind of task. But I always find it extremely slow for unknown reason. Now I know, it is all due to PlotHighlighting which is enabled by default in MMA.
So I write a cover function to speed up ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]
PlotGrid=ResourceFunction["PlotGrid","Function"];
PlotGridFast[plots_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=PlotGrid[plots/.Annotation[x_,_,"DynamicHighlight"]:>x,opts]
Options[PlotGridFast]=Options[PlotGrid];

/.Annotation[x_,_,"DynamicHighlight"]:>x will remove PlotHighlighting effect.
Compare PlotGridFast[plots] and PlotGrid[plots], you will find the plot generated by PlotGridFast[plots] will not slow down the frontend while scrolling mouse.
